# QObject:connect No such slot issue

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, signals-slots

I have no clue as to why its happening. I have extended `QObject` and also added the macro `Q_OBJECT`. Also signal and slot both has same parameter.

I have posted the original question

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Object-connect-No-such-slot-problem/m-p/2486753

This is my hpp file:

```
/*
 * LocationMonitor.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 13, 2013
 *      Author: Roland
 */

#ifndef LOCATIONMONITOR_HPP_
#define LOCATIONMONITOR_HPP_

#include <QObject>
#include <QtLocationSubset/qgeopositioninfo.h>
#include <QtLocationSubset/qgeoareamonitor.h>

using namespace Qt;
using namespace QtMobilitySubset;
class GeoNotification;
class LocationMonitor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LocationMonitor(int id,GeoNotification *geoNotification,QVariantList locationList,QVariantList actionList);
    virtual ~LocationMonitor();

public slots:
    void areaEnteredd(QtMobilitySubset::QGeoPositionInfo info);
    void areaExitedd(QtMobilitySubset::QGeoPositionInfo info);

public:
    QGeoAreaMonitor *monitor;
};

#endif /* LOCATIONMONITOR_HPP_ */
```

This is my cpp file

```
/*
 * LocationMonitor.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 13, 2013
 *      Author: Roland
 */

#include "LocationMonitor.hpp"

LocationMonitor::LocationMonitor(int id,GeoNotification *geoNotification,QVariantList locationList,QVariantList actionList):
geoNotification(geoNotification)
{
    monitor = QGeoAreaMonitor::createDefaultMonitor(this);
    QObject::connect(monitor, SIGNAL(areaEntered(QGeoPositionInfo)),this, SLOT(areaEnteredd(QGeoPositionInfo)));
    QObject::connect(monitor, SIGNAL(areaExited(QGeoPositionInfo)),this, SLOT(areaExitedd(QGeoPositionInfo)));
}
LocationMonitor::~LocationMonitor() {}

void LocationMonitor::areaEnteredd(QGeoPositionInfo info)
{
}
void LocationMonitor::areaExitedd(QGeoPositionInfo info)
{
}
```

API doc link is in [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qtmobilitysubset__qgeoareamonitor.html#function-areaentered-update)

Thanks.

Comment: The core of the question should not depend on off-site links. Can you edit the code into the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the same name everywhere: in the signal declaration, in the slot declaration and in the connect. That is because the `connect()` mechanism is based on textual comparison.

As the original signal is declared with only `const QGeoPositionInfo &` as parameter, you need to set this, and only this, too.

Here are the declarations you should use:

```
    // Header
    public slots:
        void areaEnteredd(const QGeoPositionInfo& info);
        void areaExitedd(const QGeoPositionInfo& info);

    // CPP
    void LocationMonitor::areaEnteredd(const QGeoPositionInfo& info)
    {
    }
    void LocationMonitor::areaExitedd(const QGeoPositionInfo& info)
    {
    }
    // Connects
    QObject::connect(monitor, SIGNAL(areaEntered(const QGeoPositionInfo&)),this, SLOT(areaEnteredd(const QGeoPositionInfo&)));
    QObject::connect(monitor, SIGNAL(areaExited(const QGeoPositionInfo&)),this, SLOT(areaExitedd(const QGeoPositionInfo&)));
```

Note that you'll have to use the `QtMobilitySubset` namespace in your header, which is bad. You can limit the scope to what you really need: `using ::QtMobilitySubset::QGeoPositionInfo;` instead of a full `using namespace QtMobilitySubset;`.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring your slots to take this variable: `QtMobilitySubset::QGeoPositionInfo &info` but on `connect` specifying they take `QGeoPositionInfo &` instead. As you've declared them with `QtMobilitySubset::QGeoPositionInfo &` you need to have the `QtMobilitySubset` on your `connect` statement.